# Poner una variable como titulo en una consulta sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, transacciones

Quiero que me muestre un dato variable en el encabezado.

Cuando hago esto:

```
declare @dato char(6)
declare @sql varchar(800)
set @dato='201601'
select @sql='select @dato as '+ @dato
exec(@sql)
```

Me sale este error:

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1 Must declare the scalar variable "@dato".

Y yo quiero que me aparezca así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Necesitas agregar las comillas simples para que @dato se entienda como string:

```
declare @dato char(6)
declare @sql varchar(800)
set @dato = '201601';

select @sql='select ''' + @dato + ''' as ' + QUOTENAME(@dato);
exec(@sql);
```

Otra forma es que uses `sp_executesql`, que permite pasar parámetros:

```
declare @dato char(6)
declare @sql nvarchar(800)
set @dato = '201601'

select @sql = N'select @dato as ' + QUOTENAME(@dato);

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql, N'@dato char(6)', @dato = @dato;
```

Comment: no vi cuando coloco adentro de las comillas el dato xD

Answer (score 0):

Coloca punto y coma luego del char(6)

```
declare @dato char(6);
declare @sql varchar(800);
set @dato='201601';
select @sql='select @dato as '+ @dato;
exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Esto no va a entregar el resultado explicado en la pregunta